# While loop in foreach resulting in blank page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, foreach

I really can't figure out this one!

I'm trying to show data from a database in the following fashion:

- A **FOREACH loop** that loops through an array ($jaren) of 12 values. (users can pick one of these values with a 'select' input in the form at the beginning, not shown here)
- A **WHILE loop IN the foreach loop** which *should* loop through every row in the database for which the fifth column equals the to value of the $jaren array that is 'on' (the foreach loops through eah of these values).

A little more visual:

> 1e bach BMW:
>
> > Table with ALL rows of table for which the 5th column equals '1e bach BMW'
>
> 2e bach BMW:
>
> > Table with ALL rows of table for which the 5th column equals '2e bach BMW'
>
> And so on...

The culprit seems to be the **expression of the while loop ($row[5] = $jaar)**, but I can't figure out what's wrong with it. When I load the page, I get a perfectly blank screen.

```
$results = $DB->q("SELECT * FROM `jaartrui_zoekertjes`");
$row = $DB->fa($results);
$jaren = array('1e bach BMW', '2e bach BMW', '3e bach BMW', '1e master BMW', '2e master BMW', '1e bach GNK', '2e bach GNK', '3e bach GNK', '1e master GNK', '2e master GNK', '3e master GNK', '4e master GNK');

foreach($jaren as $jaar) {
    echo "<b class='blauw'>".$jaar."</b>"
        ."<table><tr><th>Naam</th><th>E-mailadres</th><th>Ik heb</th><th>Ik wil</th></tr>";
        
        while ($row[5] = $jaar) {
            echo "<tr>"
                ."<td>".format_text($row[3])." ".format_text($row[2])."</td>"
                ."<td><a href='mailto:".format_text($row[4])."'>".format_text($row[4])."</td>"
                ."<td>".format_text($row[6])."</td>"
                ."<td>".format_text($row[7])."</td>"
                ."</tr><tr>"
                ."<td><b>Opmerkingen: </b>".format_text($row[8])."</td>"
                ."</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";    
}
```

Anyone? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at your error logs? You do have error logging turned on don;t you?

Answer (score 2):

**update**

When working with a DBMS you can (and should) use queries for matters of comparison and especially if you only want to fetch some columns.

```
foreach($jaren as $jaar) {
    //...
    $results = $DB->q("SELECT * FROM `jaartrui_zoekertjes` WHERE column = `$jaar`");
    while ($row = $DB->fa($results)) {
        //...
    }
}
```

(Replace `column` with name of the column) Now in `while()` you will only have the wanted rows and can display them like wanted. This time `=` is correct in the while, since you want to assign `$row` the retrieved values, also `fa()` (fetch all?) should return false when there isn't any row left to fetch and break the while.

Of course you could fetch all rows at first as you did. But there are following problems with this practice

1. You will need to check in PHP whether `column == $jaar` and therefore loop through all rows. In every iteration of the foreach, this can be very time consuming
2. Say you have rows with no matching column (at all), you will still retrieve those from the database and have to check all of them for matching $jaar, this brings us back to 1.

One could argue that the check for the condition has also occur in your database (how else would it know which rows to return?), but keep in mind that these systems are specially designed for fast querying as you want in this case. So in most cases you will be better off with letting the database do as much work as it can.

---

*original answer*

`$row[5] = $jaar` is assigning `$row[5]` the value `$jaar` and will equal true (unless $jaar is a falsey). You probably meant to write something like

```
while ($row[5] == $jaar) {
```

And since PHP only outputs after the execution is finished, having something like the following will get you a blank page as well

```
while (true)
    print "something";
```

Instead of endless "something"s across the screen

Answer (score 0):

(As stated in the other answer: `$row[5] = $jaar` is assignment not a logical operation.

Also in

```
    while ($row[5] = $jaar) {
        echo "<tr>"
            ."<td>".format_text($row[3])." ".format_text($row[2])."</td>"
            ."<td><a href='mailto:".format_text($row[4])."'>".format_text($row[4])."</td>"
            ."<td>".format_text($row[6])."</td>"
            ."<td>".format_text($row[7])."</td>"
            ."</tr><tr>"
            ."<td><b>Opmerkingen: </b>".format_text($row[8])."</td>"
            ."</tr>";
    }
```

I see no where where $row[5] or $jaar change. Therefore you are running and endless loop (in the event the loop is hit at all). Which would lead to nothing being pass to the browser, and would just keep chugging until the page times out.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your `$row` variable holds set of rows. So maybe try to loop through it. Now it looks like you try to compare whole 6th row instead of 6th value of the row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want something more like:

```
$results = $DB->q("SELECT * FROM `jaartrui_zoekertjes`");
$jaren = array('1e bach BMW', '2e bach BMW', '3e bach BMW', '1e master BMW', '2e master BMW', '1e bach GNK', '2e bach GNK', '3e bach GNK', '1e master GNK', '2e master GNK', '3e master GNK', '4e master GNK');

foreach($jaren as $jaar) {
    echo "<b class='blauw'>".$jaar."</b>"
        ."<table><tr><th>Naam</th><th>E-mailadres</th><th>Ik heb</th><th>Ik wil</th></tr>";

        while ($row = $DB->fa($results)) {
            if ($row[5] != $jaar) {
              continue;
            }
            echo "<tr>"
                ."<td>".format_text($row[3])." ".format_text($row[2])."</td>"
                ."<td><a href='mailto:".format_text($row[4])."'>".format_text($row[4])."</td>"
                ."<td>".format_text($row[6])."</td>"
                ."<td>".format_text($row[7])."</td>"
                ."</tr><tr>"
                ."<td><b>Opmerkingen: </b>".format_text($row[8])."</td>"
                ."</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";    
}
```

In this case, you loop through the entire database for each value of `$jaren` comparing the 5th column of each row to `$jaar`.  Clearly, this is an extremely inefficient solution and you might want to re-think your approach.  Perhaps loop through the database once, seeing if the 5th column matches any of the values in `$jaren`, then, if it does, stuffing the results into a new array or object and sorting by the '$jaar' values after.